# Why does the query to the Sharepoint API search on the internet explorer not work?

Tags: sharepoint-online, query, internet-explorer, search-api

I am using the api search to make a query and get the value of a refinablestring. A basic example of the query I am doing is the following.

```
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='Path:https:%2f%2fmysite.sharepoint.com%2fsites%2fIntranet%2fLists%2fmylist%2f'&rowlimit=100&selectproperties='RefinableString00%2cCreatedBy%2cListItemID'&refinementfilters='and(RefinableString03: %22*myValueA*%22 ,RefinableString01: %22*myValueB*%22 )'&sortlist='LastModifiedTime:descending'&clienttype='UI'
```

To find out what the problem was, I tried to launch the query directly in the address bar of the browser.
If I run it on google chrome, it correctly returns the results within a table inside the RelevantResults tag that is inside the PrimaryQueryResult tag.

But the problem comes if I run the same query in internet explorer, in that case the result table is empty. The query is exactly the same in both cases.

Anyone know what the problem may be for this to happen? Do I have to add some specific configuration in internet explorer for this to work?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see you encoded the comma (,) also in the select clause. Please also for better standards don't include additional spaces in the values.

Try the below query

https://mysite.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='Path:https:%2f%2fmysite.sharepoint.com%2fsites%2fIntranet%2fLists%2fmylist%2f'&rowlimit=100&selectproperties='RefinableString00,CreatedBy,ListItemID'&refinementfilters='and(RefinableString03:%22*myValueA*%22,RefinableString01:%22*myValueB*%22)'&sortlist='LastModifiedTime:descending'&clienttype='UI'

-Praveen.